# Add key and list value to a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have this basic list dictionary `{'2011': ['William', 'George', 'Nancy'], '2012': ['Joe', 'Math']}` that I want to add a key and list but it doesn't work

here my code:

```
 my_dict = {"2011": ["William", "George", "Nancy"], "2012": ["Joe", "Math"]}
   
    new_years = "2013"
    new_name = ["Alex", "Markus"]

    my_dict.update[new_years: new_name]
    print(my_dict)
```

Here is the excepted output that I am looking for:

`{'2011': ['William', 'George', 'Nancy'], '2012': ['Joe', 'Math'], '2013': ["Alex", "Markus"]}`

Comment: `my_dict[new_years] = new_name`

Comment: `my_dict[new_years] = new_name`.  Or if you want to be able to merge it with existing data, `my_dict.setdefault(new_years, []).extend(new_name)`.

Comment: `my_dict.update[new_years: new_name]` update is a function, so you need parentheses `()` to call it.  But you're using square brackets `[]` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is not valid Python, see this:

```
my_dict = {"2011": ["William", "George", "Nancy"], "2012": ["Joe", "Math"]}

new_years = "2013"
new_name = ["Alex", "Markus"]

my_dict.update({new_years: new_name})

# or my_dict[new_years] = new_name
print(my_dict)
```